# SQL Server 2012 LIMITing query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, limit

Okay so I need to make an SQL query that will perform the same as this MySQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT userID 
FROM gallery 
ORDER BY userID ASC 
LIMIT 0, 3
```

The SQL query that I have now looks like this, but it won't do the same job because of the second row still having the `userID`

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3  userID
FROM gallery
WHERE imageID NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 imageID
    FROM gallery
    ORDER BY userID
) 
ORDER BY userID;
```

The table looks something like this

```
imageID userID  albumID
---------------------------
1       user1   2008
2       user1   2008
3       user1   2008
4       user1   Wild Fees
5       user1   Wild Fees
6       user1   Wild Fees
7       user1   Wild Fees
8       user1   Billfish 15000
9       user1   Billfish 15000
10      user1   Billfish 15000
11      user1   Billfish 15000
12      user1   2009
13      user1   2009
14      user1   2009
15      user2   New Album Name 001
16      user2   New Album Name 001
17      user2   New Album Name 001
18      user2   New Album Name 001
19      user2   New Album Name 001
20      user2   New Album Name 001
21      user2   New Album Name 001
22      user2   New Album Name 001
23      user2   New Album Name 001
24      user2   New Album Name 001
25      user2   New Album Name 001
26      user3   qweee
27      user3   qweee
28      user3   qweee
29      user3   qweee
```

=== EDIT ===
The expected output of this specific SQL is

```
|userID|
--------
|user2 |
|user3 |
```

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: @marc_s I added that as an edit to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new offset functions in 2012:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userID 
FROM gallery
ORDER BY userID ASC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: wow... that would've been handy to know a long time ago... Thanks so much, this also simplifies all my querries

Comment: You are welcome. Only works in sql server 2012 onwards!

Answer (score 1):

I have not used MYSQL, so not sure whether your MYSQL query skips the 1st row or not. PLease double check that.

And if you really want to take out the top user id, you can try this one.

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3  userID
FROM gallery
WHERE userID NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 userID
    FROM gallery
    ORDER BY userID
) 
ORDER BY userID;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
SELECT TOP 3 userID 
FROM gallery
GROUP BY userID 
ORDER BY userID ASC ;
```

EDIT: (based on getting rows 2-4 rather than 1-3)

In SQL Server 2012, you can use `offset` and `fetch`:

```
SELECT userID 
FROM gallery
GROUP BY userID 
ORDER BY userID ASC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: this won't work because it won't skip the 1st userID

Comment: @5tar-Kaster . . . The expression `limit 0, 3` in MySQL takes the first three rows, without skipping any.  You can check the documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3  userID
FROM gallery
WHERE userID NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 userID
    FROM gallery
    ORDER BY imageID
) 
ORDER BY userID;